# How to "new" a returned function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to simulate a namespace feature in Javascript.

```
var com                   = {};
com.domain                = {};
com.domain.system         = {};
com.domain.net            = {};
com.domain.net.ip         = {};
com.domain.net.ip.tcp     = {};
com.domain.net.ip.udp     = {};
com.domain.net.ip.ssl     = {};
com.domain.util           = {};
com.domain.util.timer     = {};
com.domain.plugins        = {};
com.domain.session        = {};
com.domain.io             = {};
com.domain.algorithm      = {};
com.domain.debug          = {};
```

This is the namespaces declaration. Later I will add functions to these namespaces.

This is my selector function:

For a convenient way to use namespaces, I add a function named $. This function will walk all namespaces in com. If the selected name exists, return the object.

```
function $ (selector) {
  function digger (namespace, selector) {
    for (var prop in namespace) {
      if (typeof namespace[prop] == "array" || typeof namespace[prop] == "object") {
        if (prop == selector) {
          return namespace[prop];
        }
        var dig = digger(namespace[prop], selector);
        if (dig != null) {
          return dig;
        }
      } else {
        if (prop == selector) {
          return namespace[prop];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return digger (com, selector);
}
```

After that, I add a timer to namespace `com.doamin.util`.

```
com.domain.util.timer = function () {
    this._handle = new InnerObj.SystemTimer(io);
    return this;
};

com.domain.util.timer.prototype.expiresFromNow = function (seconds, cbHandler) { 
    this._handle.ExpiresFromNow (seconds, cbHandler);
};

com.domain.util.timer.prototype.wait = function (seconds, cbHandler) { 
    this._handle.Wait (seconds, cbHandler);
};

com.domain.util.timer.prototype.expiresAt = function (seconds, cbHandler) { 
    this._handle.Wait (seconds, cbHandler);
};

com.domain.util.timer.prototype.cancel = function () {
    this._handle.Cancel ();    
};
```

Usage:

```
 1. var timer = new com.domain.util.timer ();            OK
    timer.expiresAt (1, {});                             OK
 2. var func = $("timer");                               OK 
    var timer =  new func ();                            OK 
    timer.expiresAt (1, {});                             OK
```

But but but but but

```
var timer = new $("timer") ();                           NG
```

Can anyone tell me why the last `new` function is not working?

Comment: JavaScript != Java.  Are you **SURE** you want to do this?

Comment: What message are you getting?

Comment: Maybe this is the only way that I found to name my functions. :)

There is a mistake in usage. already fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `var timer = new ($("timer"))();`.

Your question is not clear but I guess since `$("timer")` returns a function, you want a new instance of the result of `$("timer")` and not a new instance of $().

Comment: does any way that i don't need to add additional () in new ($("timer"))();  I mean only new $("timer") ();

Comment: Unfortunately not; [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) has the highest precedence here.